# Format output in columns

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I was wondering how to format the following output:

```
-0.3116274D-04
-0.2389361D-04
-0.1192458D-04
0.3306203D-04
0.2534987D-04
0.1265136D-04
-0.2167920D-04
-0.3713258D-04
-0.2294900D-05
-0.4151710D-05
-0.7674479D-03
-0.5749288D-04
0.1393479D-04
0.6763913D-04
0.2515100D-05
-0.3638000D-06
-0.2630000D-06
-0.2445230D-06
0.1534680D-05
0.1579750D-04
0.2922010D-04
0.5390530D-04
0.8701990D-04
0.1132741D-03
0.9665700D-04
0.3337340D-04
-0.4121240D-05
```

into five columns, by transposing first:

```
-0.3116274D-04  -0.2389361D-04  -0.1192458D-04   0.3306203D-04   0.2534987D-04
 0.1265136D-04  -0.2167920D-04  -0.3713258D-04  -0.2294900D-05  -0.4151710D-05
-0.7674479D-03  -0.5749288D-04   0.1393479D-04   0.6763913D-04   0.2515100D-05
-0.3638000D-06  -0.2630000D-06  -0.2445230D-06   0.1534680D-05   0.1579750D-04
 0.2922010D-04   0.5390530D-04   0.8701990D-04   0.1132741D-03   0.9665700D-04
 0.3337340D-04  -0.4121240D-05
```

My first approach was:

```
sed 's/\n//g' File | column -n
```

Comment: Process the input line by line, adding the value to an array. When you get to a line that's a multiple of 5, or reach the end of the input, print the array and empty it.

Comment: `sed` can't remove newlines because it processes the input line by line, and doesn't see the newlines. Try using `tr` to translate newlines to spaces.

Comment: You can almost use `pr -5 -l1 -t` but it will left justify the columns, so the `-` signs won't be presented correctly.  OTOH, you could then feed the output into `awk` to do the right-justification: `pr -5 -l1 -t File | awk '{ printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }'`, but if you're going to drag `awk` into the game, it can also do the 'transposition' for you — it just takes a bit more coding to do that, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , your suggestion almost works ... when I tried it, I get: `  0.8725220D-  0.1609633D-   0.2598447D-`  The exponent of each number is gone :(

Comment: Urg; you'll need to tell `pr` how wide the output is, and/or set the inter-column character from tab to space.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```
printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n" $(cat data.txt)
```

Comment: You win :-). According to the [printf](http://man.cx/printf) manpage: _The format string is reused as often as necessary to satisfy the arguments._

Answer (score 8):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850574/15168) by [traybold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2900904/traybold) using `printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n" $(cat data.txt)` and should probably be used, but be aware that the last line is blank padded to full width. Also, if the data file is very big (256 KiB perhaps; almost certainly before you reach 1 MiB), you will run out of space for the command line arguments to `printf`.  The solutions below will work with files that are many megabytes in size without adversely affecting the system.

You can almost use `pr` in multi-column mode (`pr -5 -l1 -t`), but it left-justifies the columns, so the `-` signs won't be presented correctly. OTOH, you could then feed the output into awk to do the right-justification:

```
pr -5 -l1 -t File | awk '{ printf "%14s %14s %14s %14s %14s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }'
```

but if you're going to drag `awk` into the game, it can also do the 'transposition' for you — it just takes a bit more coding to do that, though.

> Your suggestion almost works, but when I tried it, I get: `0.8725220D- 0.1609633D- 0.2598447D-`; the exponent of each number is gone.

Some of the wonders of `pr`.  By default, it uses tabs to separate columns.  You can override that with `-s' '` or by specifying that the output width is wider (e.g. `-w100`). Note that argument values such as the space need to be attached to the option, at least in traditional implementations of `pr` (but `-w 100` works OK).

```
$ pr -s' ' -5 -l1 -t data | awk '{printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}'
-0.3116274D-04  -0.2389361D-04  -0.1192458D-04   0.3306203D-04   0.2534987D-04
 0.1265136D-04  -0.2167920D-04  -0.3713258D-04  -0.2294900D-05  -0.4151710D-05
-0.7674479D-03  -0.5749288D-04   0.1393479D-04   0.6763913D-04   0.2515100D-05
-0.3638000D-06  -0.2630000D-06  -0.2445230D-06   0.1534680D-05   0.1579750D-04
 0.2922010D-04   0.5390530D-04   0.8701990D-04   0.1132741D-03   0.9665700D-04
 0.3337340D-04  -0.4121240D-05                                                
$ pr -w 100 -5 -l1 -t data | awk '{printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}'
-0.3116274D-04  -0.2389361D-04  -0.1192458D-04   0.3306203D-04   0.2534987D-04
 0.1265136D-04  -0.2167920D-04  -0.3713258D-04  -0.2294900D-05  -0.4151710D-05
-0.7674479D-03  -0.5749288D-04   0.1393479D-04   0.6763913D-04   0.2515100D-05
-0.3638000D-06  -0.2630000D-06  -0.2445230D-06   0.1534680D-05   0.1579750D-04
 0.2922010D-04   0.5390530D-04   0.8701990D-04   0.1132741D-03   0.9665700D-04
 0.3337340D-04  -0.4121240D-05  
$
```

All these `pr | awk` solutions blank-pad the last line to full width.

Here are two equivalent `awk` scripts that do the job in one command.  One spreads the code over 2 lines, the other over 16 lines (but it is easier to read):

Option 1:

```
awk '{ a[i++] = $0; if (i == 5) { printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]; i = 0; } }
     END { if (i > 0) { printf "%14s", a[0]; for (j = 1; j < i; j++) printf "  %14s", a[j]; printf "\n"; } }' data
```

Option 2:

```
awk '{  a[i++] = $0
        if (i == 5)
        {
            printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]
            i = 0
        }
     }
     END {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            printf "%14s", a[0]
            for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
                printf "  %14s", a[j]
            printf "\n"
        }
     }' data
```

The output is the same as before except that neither of these blank-pads the last line:

```
-0.3116274D-04  -0.2389361D-04  -0.1192458D-04   0.3306203D-04   0.2534987D-04
 0.1265136D-04  -0.2167920D-04  -0.3713258D-04  -0.2294900D-05  -0.4151710D-05
-0.7674479D-03  -0.5749288D-04   0.1393479D-04   0.6763913D-04   0.2515100D-05
-0.3638000D-06  -0.2630000D-06  -0.2445230D-06   0.1534680D-05   0.1579750D-04
 0.2922010D-04   0.5390530D-04   0.8701990D-04   0.1132741D-03   0.9665700D-04
 0.3337340D-04  -0.4121240D-05
```

It would be easier and shorter to write code that did; the reset code would also do `delete a` to clear the array and the END block would simply test `i` and use the `printf` from the main code:

```
awk '{  a[i++] = $0
        if (i == 5)
        {
            printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]
            i = 0
            delete a
        }
     }
     END {
        if (i > 0) printf "%14s  %14s  %14s  %14s  %14s\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]
     }' data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%5?FS:RS)}1' file
-0.3116274D-04 -0.2389361D-04 -0.1192458D-04 0.3306203D-04 0.2534987D-04
0.1265136D-04 -0.2167920D-04 -0.3713258D-04 -0.2294900D-05 -0.4151710D-05
-0.7674479D-03 -0.5749288D-04 0.1393479D-04 0.6763913D-04 0.2515100D-05
-0.3638000D-06 -0.2630000D-06 -0.2445230D-06 0.1534680D-05 0.1579750D-04
0.2922010D-04 0.5390530D-04 0.8701990D-04 0.1132741D-03 0.9665700D-04
0.3337340D-04 -0.4121240D-05 $
```

Note that it doesn't put a newline at the end if the number of lines aren't a multiple of 5. Is that a concern?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, haven't seen this in a while. There are several ways:

The ol' [pr](http://man.cx/pr) command was used for this type of work -- especially if you wanted those columns going vertically instead of horizontally.

However, I would use `printf` which allows me to keep the text a constant width, and then use a counter and the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator to count when I have five items in a line. The *modulo* operator is sometimes called a *remainder* operator. However, it functions like a clock:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 

count=0
while read number
do
    ((count+=1))
    printf "%14.14s  " $number
    if ((count % 5 == 0))
    then
        printf "\n"
    fi
done < $file
printf "\n"
```

The format for the `printf` is missing the minus ( i.e. `%-14.14s`) which forces the text to be aligned to the right instead of the left. That way the minus doesn't throw me off.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit tricky alternative:

```
columnPrint(){
select foo in $(cat); do break; done; <<!SELECTEOF
1
!SELECTEOF
};

cat data.txt | columnPrint;
# or simply columnPrint < data.txt
```

Compared with @traybold approach, it has the drawback that items are numbered (which could not be what you want), but it also has the advantage of automatically adapting the number of columns to the input strings and terminal width.