# Convert rows to columns with bash

Tags: bash

I have a large text file that looks like the example below. It has many more groups of rows seperated by an empty row.

```
Aggr2_N1_SATA
Normal
192.168.1.2:/floluesxprd5_ds_vol1
Unknown
522.50 GB
478.69 GB
NFS
10/14/2020 3:21:52 PM
Enabled
Disabled
Not supported

boot_lun_svr1
Normal
NETAPP Fibre Channel Disk (naa.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):3
Non-SSD
5.00 GB
4.29 GB
VMFS5
2/10/2020 4:26:37 PM
Enabled
Disabled
Supported
```

I would like to convert it to look like this:

```
Aggr2_N1_SATA,Normal,192.168.1.2:/floluesxprd5_ds_vol1,Unknown,522.50 GB,478.69 GB,NFS,10/14/2020,3:21:52 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Not supported

boot_lun_svr1,Normal,NETAPP Fibre Channel Disk (naa.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):3,Non-SSD,5.00 GB,4.29 GB,VMFS5,2/10/2020 4:26:37 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Supported
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

perl:

```
perl -00 -lpe 's/\n/,/g' file
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `perl -00lpe 'y/\n/,/'`.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, golf champion!

Comment: Yes, I did used to compete at Perl golf years ago ;-)

Comment: one less char: `perl -00lpe y/\\n/,/`

Comment: Goddamnit I'm rusty :-(  Although I'm pretty that with the original Perl golf rules, the quotes don't count anyway.

Comment: Guys, youre incredible. Never understand how one could learn perl up to those levels. Congrats, really.

Comment: @jm666, for me, the secret to perl one-liners is understanding what `-n` and `-p` do. Then, read [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) to figure out some other handy command line switches (`-a` and `-F`, `-l`, `-00` and `-0777`, `-M`)

Comment: Glen, yeah. The problem is than I know all switches (used in my answer the `-00` too), only didn't get the right idea when and how use them. This code-golf is an really wonderfull experiance. ;) thanx. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=, '{$1 = $1} 1' file
```

Output:

```
Aggr2_N1_SATA,Normal,192.168.1.2:/floluesxprd5_ds_vol1,Unknown,522.50 GB,478.69 GB,NFS,10/14/2020 3:21:52 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Not supported    
boot_lun_svr1,Normal,NETAPP Fibre Channel Disk (naa.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):3,Non-SSD,5.00 GB,4.29 GB,VMFS5,2/10/2020 4:26:37 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Supported
```

With spaces between:

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=, '{$1 = $1} NR > 1 { print "" } 1' file
```

Output:

```
Aggr2_N1_SATA,Normal,192.168.1.2:/floluesxprd5_ds_vol1,Unknown,522.50 GB,478.69 GB,NFS,10/14/2020 3:21:52 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Not supported

boot_lun_svr1,Normal,NETAPP Fibre Channel Disk (naa.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):3,Non-SSD,5.00 GB,4.29 GB,VMFS5,2/10/2020 4:26:37 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Supported
```

With spaces after every line:

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=, -v ORS='\n\n' '{$1 = $1} 1' file
```

Comment: +1 For all the variations, 1 of which matches OP's exact desired output.

Comment: `{$1 = $1} 1` ... good ol' awk, nobody knows what it means, but it works :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using GNU `sed` to complete the rout. Please note that this is only for reference and you are better off using [glenn jackman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25318081/970195) `perl` solution as that is portable and easy to understand.

Easy way is to read the entire file in one long string separated by `,` and then putting newlines when two consecutive `,` are seen.

```
sed '
    :a;            # Create a label a for a loop
    $!N;           # Append the next line to pattern space if it is not the last line
    s/\n/,/;       # Substitute the newline with ,
    ta;            # If the substitution modified pattern space repeat the loop
    s/,,/\n\n/g    # At the end, substitute two , with two newlines
' file
```

#### One-liner form:

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\n/,/;ta;s/,,/\n\n/g' file
```

However, reading entire file in one long string is not an efficient solution. So there is a paragraph mode for `sed` which allows you to work with one paragraph at a time.

```
sed '
    /./ {          # If it is not a blank line
        H;         # Append the pattern space to hold space
        $!d        # Delete it if it is not the last line
    }
    x              # When we encounter a blank line, we swap the pattern and hold space
    s/\n//         # We remove the first empty newline
    s/\n/,/g       # Replace all newlines with ,
    $!G            # If it not the last line swap hold and pattern space for blank lines
' file
```

#### One-liner form:

```
sed '/./{H;$!d};x;s/\n//;s/\n/,/g;$!G' file
```

#### Output in both cases:

```
Aggr2_N1_SATA,Normal,192.168.1.2:/floluesxprd5_ds_vol1,Unknown,522.50 GB,478.69 GB,NFS,10/14/2020 3:21:52 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Not supported

boot_lun_svr1,Normal,NETAPP Fibre Channel Disk (naa.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):3,Non-SSD,5.00 GB,4.29 GB,VMFS5,2/10/2020 4:26:37 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe '$comma and !/^$/ and  print "," ;$comma = !/^$/ and chomp or print "\n"' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could works

```
perl -00 -F"\n" -lanE 'say join(",", @F)'
```

prints

```
Aggr2_N1_SATA,Normal,192.168.1.2:/floluesxprd5_ds_vol1,Unknown,522.50 GB,478.69 GB,NFS,10/14/2020 3:21:52 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Not supported
boot_lun_svr1,Normal,NETAPP Fibre Channel Disk (naa.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):3,Non-SSD,5.00 GB,4.29 GB,VMFS5,2/10/2020 4:26:37 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Supported
```

and the

```
 perl -00 -F"\n" -lanE 'say join(",", @F),"\n"'
```

prints

```
Aggr2_N1_SATA,Normal,192.168.1.2:/floluesxprd5_ds_vol1,Unknown,522.50 GB,478.69 GB,NFS,10/14/2020 3:21:52 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Not supported

boot_lun_svr1,Normal,NETAPP Fibre Channel Disk (naa.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx):3,Non-SSD,5.00 GB,4.29 GB,VMFS5,2/10/2020 4:26:37 PM,Enabled,Disabled,Supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer ([Format output in columns [bash, grep, sed, awk]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850403/format-output-in-columns-bash-grep-sed-awk)) if every eleven rows are being transposed:

```
printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" $(sed 's/ /_/g' file_name) | sed 's/_/ /g'
```

Comment: That's not going to work because some of the lines have whitespace.

Comment: Updated: but the perl solution looks so much more elegant

Comment: That's not the right technique. The original data contains underscores already, so you'll replace them with spaces. In general, it's hard to assume a character that you *hope* won't appear in the input.

Comment: This would work, requires bash 4: `sed '/^$/d' file | { mapfile -t lines; printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n\n" "${lines[@]}"; }`