# fmt with Multiple Columns

Tags: bash, shell, text, format, text-manipulation

Is there a way for `fmt` to output text formatted with multiple columns (doesn't seem to be anything about this in the man page so I doubt this)? If not, is there a command that is like `fmt` but can output multi-column'd text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format output in columns \[bash, grep, sed, awk\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850403/format-output-in-columns-bash-grep-sed-awk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `pr`

```
fmt -35 < file | pr -2 -T
```

Check the man pages to fine-tune the  options