# bash shell: echo 3 list of output netstat to 3 column

Tags: bash, shell, echo, netstat

Hi every one i have a script shell like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
netstatport80=`netstat -an|grep :80 |awk '!/:8080/'|awk '!/:8081/' |awk '{print $5}'|cut -d":" -f1|sort|uniq -c|sort -rn| grep -v "0.0.0.0"`

netstatport443=`netstat -an|grep :443 |awk '!/:8080/'|awk '{print $5}'|cut -d":" -f1|sort|uniq -c|sort -rn| grep -v "0.0.0.0"`

netstatESTA=`netstat -an|grep ESTA |awk '!/:8080/'|awk '{print $5}'|cut -d":" -f1|sort|uniq -c|sort -rn| grep -v "0.0.0.0"`

echo '
List IP request port 80:    List IP request port 443:    List IP request ESTA:
'$netstatport80'            '$netstatport443'           '$netstatESTA'

'
```

How i can have a output like that:

```
List IP request port 80:    List IP request port 443:    List IP request ESTA:
123.x.x.x                    183.x.x.x                   153.x.x.x
193.x.x.x                    123.x.x.x                   164.x.x.x
130.x.x.x                    103.x.x.x                   101.x.x.x
187.x.x.x                    173.x.x.x                   185.x.x.x
```

Thanks all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste` is the standard tool for your need, it will join multiple files into columns :

```
$ echo """A
> a
> a
> a""" > A.txt

$ echo """B
> b
> b""" > B.txt

$ echo """C
> c
> c
> c
> c
> c""" > C.txt

$ paste A.txt B.txt C.txt
AAAA    BB      C
a       b       c
a       b       c
a               c
a               c
a               c
                c
                c
```

It works on files so you should write the output of your filtered `netstat` commands to files, or you can use anonymous pipes :

```
paste <(echo "List IP request port 80:"; echo "$netstatport80") <(echo "List IP request port 443:"; echo "$netstatport443") <(echo "List IP request ESTA:"; echo "$netstatESTA")
```

If the sizes of the different columns break the formatting, you can use `paste`'s `-d` option to specify a delimiter between columns, then reformat them using the `column` tool, or try with `pr` which will truncate columns at a specific size (see the previous version of my answer below).

---

Edit : older answer using `pr`, which is overkill and less known.

Looks like you could be using `pr` 'merge' `-m` option :

```
$ echo """A
> a
> a
> a""" > A.txt

$ echo """B
> b
> b""" > B.txt

$ echo """C
> c
> c
> c
> c
> c""" > C.txt

$ pr -mT A.txt B.txt C.txt
A                       B                       C
a                       b                       c
a                       b                       c
a                                               c
                                                c
                                                c
```

`pr` is a pager I found out about in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850688/1678362) while researching your question, its `-m` flag answers your need and it's `-T` option disables page formatting (headers, footers, and maybe more?).
It takes input from files so you will have to redirect the output of your filtered `netstat` commands to files instead of using variables, unless you want to bother with anonymous pipes :

```
pr -mT <(echo "List IP request port 80:"; echo "$netstatport80") <(echo "List IP request port 443:"; echo "$netstatport443") <(echo "List IP request ESTA:"; echo "$netstatESTA")
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, i can't see button vote for thist answer thanks +1

Comment: @ncc heh? that's weird. Guess you can't accept it as answer either then? Well I'll make do with the satisfaction of having helped someone ;)

Comment: You can get similar result using (a more popular tool) [`paste` (1)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/paste/). Note that both `pr` and `paste` are from same package and should be available on most of the systems. However, `paste` is a tool whose primary purpose is to do this operation.

Comment: @anishsane I knew there was a more familiar tool that did it, that's what I was searching for ! You should add an answer in case people stumble on this question :)

Comment: No, you may add it to your answer... :-)